# RegExp for a specific Date format and conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, razor

I found a regular expression for (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss) [24 Hours] as

```
( ^(([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])/([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])/[1-2]\d{3}) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1})$ )
```

Can please any one provide me an RegExp for `(MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss TT)` [12 hours]. with checking condition as below,

1. yyyy >= 1970
2. dd && MM >= 01 (Double digit, not single digit).

Comment: What is TT supposed to be?

Comment: RegExp in the question is for 24 hour time format. i need it for 12 hour time format.

Comment: **Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values.** Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want regex to solve your entire issue, try this:

```
^((?:[0][1-9])|(?:[1][1-2]))/((?:[0][1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:[3][0-1]))/((?:19[7-9][0-9])|(?:[2-9][0-9]{3})) ((?:1[0-2])|(?:0[1-9])):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]) ([PA]M)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[View on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/YvRBGLB9lMyXOsb3)

Comment: Nice image! How did you generate if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: @smerny: hi, year and two digit validation is working fine. but for month it coming up to 29 and for date it is coming up to 39 and date and month should be greater that 01. this can be resolvable?. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @ThulasiRam Ah yes, I didn't think about that. Just change the day portion to this... `((?:[0][1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:[3][0-1]))` and the month to this... `((?:[0][1-9])|(?:[1][1-2]))`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do maths in regex.

```
^(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4}) (?\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})( [AP]M)?$

var groups = input.match(regex);
var valid = groups
       && Number(groups[1]) > 0 && Number(groups[1]) <= 31
       && Number(groups[2]) > 0 && Number(groups[2]) <= 12
       && Number(groups[3]) >= 1970
       && Number(groups[4]) < (groups[7] ? 12 : 24)
       && Number(groups[5]) < 60
       && Number(groups[6]) < 60
```

If you really needed to encode this in your regex, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(([0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])/([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])/[1-2]\d{3}) (20|21|22|23|[0-1]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1}):([0-5]?\d{1}) [AP]M$
```

**PS:** I just added the part to include AM/PM and didn't validate your earlier working regex.

Comment: hi, this will check the condition that Year is Greater  that or equal to 1970 and date && month should be greater that 01. RegExp in the question is for 24 hour time format. i need it for 12 hour time format.  Thanks.

Comment: May I know in which language/tool you're running this regex?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor view, i am using jquery.validate.min.js. i need to validate the text box value datetime is valid or not.